# command line http load testing tool that supports gzip / deflate

Tags: apache-2.2, http, testing, ab

We use apache as our web server and it has mod_deflate enabled.

We have been using httperf to test it for load but we've not been able to get it to talk to the webserver with gzip/deflate encoding enabled in httperf.

I tried --add-header='Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate' to httperf's command line parameters, but my apache simply doesn't respond to that(http perf reports 0 response rate)

Although Apache Bench(ab) accepts gzip/deflate encoding, we want to use httperf because we are interested in keeping the server loaded with X requests per second which ab doesn't support.

Is there a way to use httperf with g-zip/deflate encoding enabled ? Are there other command line load testing tools that'll do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add \n to the --add-header? Would --add-header='Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\n' work?

Comment: thnx a ton

Comment: No problem, have a nice weekend :)